# Sqlalchemy creating group to group relationship

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have the following models, where my two models share an outside_id to some table I don't have access to, but it is via that table they are connected. So they are not in a traditional many to many relationship. The only solution I have found is to create a table with primary key outside_id and use that to bridge the two relationships.

It adds allot of complexity, because the only thing that I need is to be able to eagerly load data from B in A and access it when I dump it to json. Is there a simpler way to do it?

```
class B(model):
    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    outside_id = Column(String())

class A(model):
    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    outside_id = Column(String())

    relationship(
        "B",
        foreign_keys=[outside_id],
        primaryjoin="A.outside_id==B.outside_id",
        viewonly=True,
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

##### Static Relationship

You can use `foreign` and `remote` to specify the relationship keys inside the primaryjoin.

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import foreign, remote, joinedload

class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'a_table'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    outside_id = Column(Integer)

    b = relationship('B', primaryjoin="foreign(A.outside_id) == remote(B.outside_id)", viewonly=True)

class B(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'b_table'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    outside_id = Column(Integer)

with Session(engine) as session:
   for a in session.scalars(select(A).options(joinedload(A.b))):
        print (a.id, a.outside_id, a.b.id if a.b else None)
```

##### Ad-hoc query

You can also just use an adhoc query with a regular `outerjoin` on the two `outside_id` columns.

```py
with Session(engine) as session:
    
    results = []
    for a, b in session.execute(select(A, B).outerjoin(B, A.outside_id == B.outside_id)):
        results.append({
            'id': a.id,
            'name': a.name,
            'b': {
                'id': b.id,
                'name': b.name,
            } if b else None
        })
```

Comment: This is using `sqlalchemy 1.4`.